# read long txt file into r without delimiter and identify 17 char string where char 16 and 17 are identical to 14 and 15

Tags: string, r, text

I have a txt file approx 40k long. there are no delimiters or structure to the txt file. I need to identify a text string within this long string 15 characters long, but I know that char 16 and 17 equals char 14 and 15 respectively. Any idea how whis can be done using r?

Comment: How does a 15 character string have a 16th and 17th character?

Comment: You should provide a clear example of input and desired output. You should probably also simplify the problem rather than posting the entire file you are actually working with.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, here's a sample string.

```
a<-"aaabbbcccddddfffeee"
```

And let's say you want to extract a 6 character string where the 5th and 6th characters match the next two characters after the string. You can find that with a regular expression like

```
regmatches(a, regexpr("(.{4}(.{2}))\\2", a))
```

However that does also grab the two extra character after the match. You can trim off the the last two characters, or you could use captured matches. I've written a helper function call [regcapturedmatches](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321) which makes this a bit easier. You could do

```
regcapturedmatches(a, regexpr("(.{4}(.{2}))\\2", a, perl=T))[[1]][,1]
```

to get just the match.